# Replace pages of one PDF with another PDF using VBA and Adobe 10

Tags: vba, adobe

I am using VBA to replace the pages of on PDF with the pages of another. I found this code but it is not working for me. While the document is saved properly the pages are not exchanged.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp

    Dim Part1Document As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim Part2Document As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

    Dim numPages As Integer

    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    Set Part1Document = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    Set Part2Document = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    Doc1.Open ("C:\temp\Part1.pdf")
    Doc2.Open ("C:\temp\Part2.pdf")

    ' Insert the pages of Part2 after the end of Part1
    numPages = Doc1.GetNumPages()

    If Doc1.InsertPages(numPages 3, Doc2,
        0, Doc2.GetNumPages(), True) = False Then
        MsgBox "Cannot insert pages"
    End If

    If Doc1.Save(PDSaveFull, "C:\temp\MergedFile.pdf") = False Then
        MsgBox "Cannot save the modified document"
    End If

    Doc1.Close
    Doc2.Close

    AcroApp.Exit
    Set AcroApp = Nothing
    Set Part1Document = Nothing
    Set Part2Document = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It (now) it is able to merge, insert, delete and insert pages. Play with it, please! For each option you must choose the appropriate Boolean variable.

For `boolMerge` option, it will merge both files, starting `Doc` pages.

For `boolReplace` it will replace a specific number of pages from `Doc1` with the same number of `Doc2`. It looks this is what this method can do.

For `boolDelInsert`, it firstly deletes 3 pages of `Doc1` and then inserts, starting from the first page, the `Doc2` pages, minus 1. I do not have such a big file and it is not (fully) tested. Since you used dummy file full names, I did not delete my pdf test files path...

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.CAcroApp
    Dim Doc1 As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
    Dim Doc2 As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc

    Dim numPages As Integer, boolNotSaved As Boolean
    Dim boolReplace As Boolean, boolDelInsert As Boolean
    Dim boolMerge As Boolean, startDel As Long, lastDel As Long 'for deletion case

    boolMerge = True 'use here boolReplace, boolDelInsert 
    startDel = 0: lastDel = 2 ' pdf pages are zero based

    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    Set Doc1 = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    Set Doc2 = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    Doc1.Open ("C:\Users\Fane Branesti\Dropbox\Get Started with Dropbox - bis.pdf")
    Doc2.Open ("C:\Users\Fane Branesti\Dropbox\combinate.pdf") ' Then Stop

    If boolReplace Then 'it replaces starting from the first parameter (0) with all Doc2 pages
        If Doc1.ReplacePages(0, Doc2, 0, Doc2.GetNumPages, 1) = False Then
            MsgBox "Cannot replace pages"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf boolMerge Then 'it add at the end of the first file, all the content of the second
        numPages = Doc1.GetNumPages()
        If Doc1.InsertPages(numPages - 1, Doc2, _
            0, Doc2.GetNumPages(), True) = False Then
            MsgBox "Cannot merge pages"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf boolDelInsert Then
        'delete first three pages (from 0 to 2)
        If Doc1.DeletePages(startDel, lastDel) <> True Then
            MsgBox "Unable to Delete"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'insert Doc2 pages (-1) starting from 0 (after -1):
        If Doc1.InsertPages(-1, Doc2, _
            0, Doc2.GetNumPages() - 1, True) = False Then
            MsgBox "Cannot merge pages"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Doc1.Save(PDSaveFlags.PDSaveFull, "C:\Users\Fane Branesti\Dropbox\ProcessedFile.pdf") = False Then
        MsgBox "Cannot save the modified document"
        boolNotSaved = True
    End If        

    Doc1.Close: Doc2.Close

    AcroApp.Exit
    Set AcroApp = Nothing: Set Doc1 = Nothing: Set Doc2 = Nothing

    If Not boolNotSaved Then MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I get "Cannot insert pages" with your code as well. Does it work on your system?

Comment: @Valentin Franke: Please refresh the page and try it now. But, like I said, it merges the two files... If this is not what you wont, we can place with `Replace`, too... And yes, it works on my system.

Comment: I still get the same message. All it does on my system is save Doc1 as MergedFile.pdf. I copied your code and just changes the folder locations. Also, strictly I want to replace pages but merging does the same, so boths works for me.

Comment: @Valentin Franke:  Why changing anything? I tested your code with my folder path and files full name, but I took care to change back to (what I thought are) yours... The single difference would be that I use `Acrobat DC` but it should create the same object like `Acrobat X Pro`. I suppose you have Adobe Acrobat  X Pro installed... Is that true? Or do you try the code with Adobe Reader...? What reference did you set?

Comment: I changed the folder path because I didn't want to expose my actual folder path. I don't think this should be a problem for the code, should it? I do have Pro and the reference I set was Adobe Acrobat 10 Type Library.

Comment: @Valentin Franke: The reference is correct (I use the same 10.0 reference). It adds the pages of `Doc2` to the end of `Doc1', in my installation. Please check if the full name of your pdf files are correct. The code does not return an error for wrong paths... But let us make some debugging. I will insert two lines to see if the code returns the pages of each pdf files...

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just to be clear: I do not get an error message from VBA but the  MsgBox "Cannot save the modified document". This were the code does not work for me.

Comment: @Valentin Franke: Let us take the problem step by step. Please, refresh (this page) and copy the adapted code. Or insert only the line `Debug.Print "Doc1: " & numPages, "Doc2: " & Doc2.GetNumPages(): Stop` after `numPages = Doc1.GetNumPages()`. What does it return in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G in VBE) when the code stops? It should return the number of pages for both your open pdf files...

Comment: @Valentin Franke: Do you have the line `If Doc1.InsertPages(numPages - 1, Doc2, _`, or you did not refresh the page and have it without `- 1`?

Comment: It does return the pages: Doc1: 90      Doc2: 124 and I know see that it did merge the two files despite giving me the message: Cannot insert pages. However, i did express not suffienctly. What I want is to take the first three pages of doc1 an add pages 2-123 of doc2.  I just tried this code:     `If Doc1.InsertPages(3, Doc2, _
        1, Doc2.GetNumPages(), True) = False Then
        MsgBox "Cannot insert pages
    End If`  But it didn't work.

Comment: @Valentin Franke:  I am afraid that `InsertPage` does what it means... It only allows inserting pages in a specific place. In order to replace pages, `Doc1.ReplacePages` should be used. I did not find any documentation, but the intellisense shows something looking logic. I tested but the result was not the one I expected. I just wonted you seeing that this error disappears and pass to the next testing phase... Now I have to do something else which cannot be postponed... I will come back after.

Comment: Thank you so far, If I find a solution in the meantime I will let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, .ReplacePage does not seem work. So I found a workaround. Using .DeletePages I deleted all the pages of doc1 and doc2 I didnt't need and then I merged them.

Comment: @Valentin Franke: I thought I wrote here a comment yesterday... I adapted (yesterday) the code making it able to Merge, Replace plus DeleteInsert (to do what I understood you need. `Replace` works, but you can replace a specific number with the same pages number, starting from a page you want. But you cannot replace 3 pages with 100. That's why I tried the last option `DeleteInsert`. I would like to receive some feedback about the code behavior...

Comment: thank you very much! The code looks promising, I am just trying to figure out the parameters. If I want to merge two pdf files as followis : Pdf1 (pages 1-3) + pdf2 (pages 2 - end) = pdf3. How would I set the parameters in your code?

Comment: @Valentin Franke: Please try `startDel = 2` and `lastDel = Doc1.GetNumPages()`, but take care give a value to the second (`lastDel`) **after `Doc1` has been loaded**!  Otherwise you will receive an error. `startDel` is 2 because Acrobat paging style is zero based (first page is 0, not 1). And, of course change  `boolMerge = True` with `boolDelInsert = True`... I only wanted to create a piece of code using all three ways. For a specific need, it can be transformed in a function taking the necessary param: (file paths, pages to be deleted, page after which to be inserted the second file pages).